# How to handle string Exception in C# when we try to enter anything other than characters in string variable

Tags: c#, .net, exception

like I want to show to enter the value of itemname in a class. then How to handle the exception when someone enters something else other than letters. Why this not working?

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Item Name");
    item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.Write("Please enter Name in the Correct Format");
    if (e.Message != null)
        z = 1;
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve].

Comment: Anything you get back from a Console.ReadLine is a letter that compose a string. What do you consider NOT to be a letter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not working because the method **ReadLine** of Console, doesn't throw exception as you are expecting.

> ReadLine method can throw this exceptions IOException, OutOfMemoryException, ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

You can check this in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

I guess you are confunding how exceptions work, so I suggest you to read this: [Exceptions and Exception Handling (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

---

To do what you want you must set the return of ReadLine in a property, and then run some code that check if this string value contains only letters, one way to do this is using Regex, see the code below

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Item Name");
item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine();

var containOnlyLetters = Regex.IsMatch(item1.itemname.Trim(), @"^[A-Za-z]+$");
```

You must add this using

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

As I can see in your code, you want to ask again if it doesn't entered the string that you allow, so lets use a do for loop to do that, see below

```
for (int tries = 0; tries == 0 || !Regex.IsMatch(item1.itemname, @"^[A-Za-z]+$"); tries++)
{
    if(tries > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Name in the Correct Format");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Item Name");
    item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
}
```

If you isn't familiar with Regex, you can create a method that check if a string contains only letters looping through all characters and checking one by one, like that:

```
private static bool ContainsOnlyLetters(string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method can be simplified using LINQ

```
private static bool ContainsOnlyLetters(string str)
{
    return str.All(c => char.IsLetter(c));
}
```

If you use C# 6 you can use expression bodied method

```
private static bool ContainsOnlyLetters(string str)
    => str.All(c => char.IsLetter(c));
```

And then you can use the method **ContainsOnlyLetters**, see below:

```
for (int tries = 0; tries == 0 || !ContainsOnlyLetters(item1.itemname.Trim()); tries++)
{
    if(tries > 0)
        Console.Write("Please enter Name in the Correct Format");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Item Name");
    item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can use a ternary expression to improve previous code a little bit

```
for (int tries = 0; tries == 0 || !ContainsOnlyLetters(item1.itemname.Trim()); tries++)
{
    var displayMessage = tries > 0
                         ? "Please enter Name in the Correct Format"
                         : "Please Enter the Item Name"
    Console.WriteLine(displayMessage);
    item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't like the `for` approach. It's the use case of `while` or `do-while`. In the other hand, why you check `tries == 0`. It will be always `true`..............

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I respect your opinion, but I don't agree that use for is bad, if you want me to change it, ok, np for me, I do it. About tries, you are wrong, `tries == 0` will be true only once, if the valued isn't allowed, the tries variable will be incremented, and tries will be 1, so 1 isn't equals to 0. Btw using this for, its also easy way to track how many tries user did.

Comment: Well, yes, I was wrong about `tries == 0`. BTW, I can still say that using `for` like a `while` is a wrong approach. It's confusing................

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Is it confusing or wrong? Sorry mate, but you didn't provided any value argue to me that explain why use `for` is wrong. If you have prejudice against the use of the `for`, and if it makes you ill, I can change, you want it?

Comment: It's almost the same issue with using exception to implement control flow. `for` isn't the tool for this problem, because when you want to do something **while some condition is true**, and C# has a loop called **while**, I need to think that you're overusing `for`.

Comment: After all, the condition in the `for` block is meant to evaluate the iteration number using some conditional, and you're mixing this with breaking the `for` loop based on some other conditional: `!ContainsOnlyLetters(item1.itemname.Trim())`. It's ugly.

Comment: BTW let the community rate your answer. It's just my humble opinion. Maybe others may consider it absolutely fiine.

Answer (score -3):

This an anti-pattern: [control flow by exceptions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).

I suspect your intention was something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Item Name");
    item1.itemname = Console.ReadLine();

    if([Put here a condition to validate item1.itemname format]) 
         throw new SomeException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.Write("Please enter Name in the Correct Format");
    if (e.Message != null)
        z = 1;
}
```

Instead of using exceptions **you should *regular expressions*, conditionals and loops to implement a trial-error approach to user input**.

For example you might use a `do-while` loop to perform iterations until the user provides an `itemName` with the valid format:

```
string itemName = null;
do
{
    // If it's not the first try you assume that itemName won't be empty
    // so it will show the message to prompt the user for a valid item name
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the item name");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an item name with valid format!");

    itemName = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!Regex.IsMatch(itemName, "^[a-z]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

// Now that you know the itemName is valid, you can set the whole property:
item1.itemname = itemName;
```

### If you need to use this input approach for many properties...

...you can generalize this approach into a method. I've also added a parameter to specify a limited number of tries until the `Prompt` method will fail:

```
// This class will hold data input results
public sealed class DataInputResult 
{
    public DataInputResult(string data, bool isSuccessful = true, string failReason = null)
    {
        Data = data;
        IsSuccessful = isSuccessful;
        FailReason = failReason;
    }
    public string Data { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; private set; }
    public bool FailReason { get; private set; }
}

public class DataInput
{
    public static Task<DataInputResult> Prompt(string initialMessage, string retryMessage, string regex, int maxTries = 3)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<DataInputResult> resultCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<DataInputResult>();

        int currentTries = 0;
        string itemName = null;
        bool matches = false;

        while(currentTries < maxTries && !matches)
        {
            // If it's not the first try you assume that itemName won't be empty
            // so it will show the message to prompt the user for a valid item name
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
                Console.WriteLine(initialMessage);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(retryMessage, currentTries + 1);

            itemName = Console.ReadLine();

            matches = Regex.IsMatch(itemName, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if(!matches) currentTries++;
        }

        if(matches)
            resultCompletionSource.SetResult(new DataInputResult(itemName));
        else
            resultCompletionSource.SetResult(new DataInputResult(null, false, "Maximum number of tries reached"));


        return resultCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

...and your code will be oversimplified to:

```
DataInputResult itemNameResult = await DataInput.Prompt
(
    "Please enter the item name", 
    "Please enter an item name with valid format! You can still try to give one {0} time(s) more...",
    "^[a-z]+$" // alphabet characters only
);      

DataInputResult itemIdResult = await DataInput.Prompt
(
    "Please enter the item identifier", 
    "Please enter an item identifier with valid format! You can still try to give one {0} time(s) more...",
    "^[0-9]+$" // digits only
);

// Set item object properties if the prompt result was successful:
if(itemNameResult.IsSuccessful)
    item.itemname = itemNameResult.Data;

if(itemIdResult.IsSuccessful)
    item.itemid = itemIdResult.Data;
```

Comment: I know you want to try use to fix the problem, but he badly know about exceptions, and you provided a class that using `async/await/TaskCompletetionSource` it's to much thing that is not simple to learn and understand, I guess you are going to confuse OP. And Btw, you said `This an anti-pattern: control flow by exceptions.` and in this Task approach you are using that, you came into contradiction.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro This isn't a competition. I know I criticized your answer because of the wrong use of `for` loop.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro In the other hand, answers aren't exclusively composed for the OP but they're also for future readers.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro The last part of generalizing the approach into a method, and the fact that's using the Task Asynchronous Pattern, doesn't defeat the purpose of my answer. I've provided the OP a path to expand his/her knowledge doing the things in the right way using modern approaches to .NET development

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Finally, about the exception thing, there's no contradiction. The exception is thrown to notify that no input from the user could be considered valid once the tries have reached the maximum tries. **Check that there's no control flow by exception in my approach**. The input validation/retrieval is performed using regexps and a while loop, and the fact that the operation can throw an exception means that **it can be handled in an upper layer, for example in a last-chance exception handler** (f.e. `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event)

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro I hope you aren't who downvoted my answer ;P because I could downvote yours because of the `for` wrong usage, but I still prefered to discuss with you about the topic, and I won't give you a downvote for this. I just consider your proposal a bad approach.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro To avoid confusion, I've replaced the exception thing with returning a result class, but I still think that the previous approach wasn't wrong (unless you used the exception to retry again or other decisions).